# NSManagedObject property managedObjectContext has no value

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data

In my code, I am trying to access `[NSManagedObject managedObjectContext]` but surprisingly it returns **nil**. The managed object is loaded because I already successfully accessed it's values using `[NSManagedObject valueForKey:]`. Is there any case where **managedObjectContext** returns **nil**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initialize a managed object directly using `init` without inserting it into a context, then it may have a nil context. If you insert it and pass a nil value for the context, it will have a nil context.

Comment: Can't say without seeing code. The only way for it to have a nil context is to never give it one. I don't even think you can set it nil once you've assigned it to one. How are you creating the managed object?

Comment: You are right TechZen, the object was mistakenly given a nil managedObjectContext at initialization. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but for me managedObjectContext was also set to nil for NSManagedObject, when this object was turned into a fault, and I didn't have strong reference to its context.

Answer (score 0):

Official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/instp/NSManagedObject/c:objc(cs)NSManagedObject(py)managedObjectContext) says:

> May be `nil` if the receiver has been deleted from its context. If the receiver is a fault, accessing this property does not cause it to fire.